# How to Fadein a ul

Tags: jquery, menu, fade

I have a CSS dropline menu on my page. I have been trying for weeks to make the dropline part (submenu) fade in when you hover over the "what we do" link. I've tried various Jquery tutorials and I have a few alternative functions working, but I can't get what I want. I'm very new to this code business so go easy :)

Here's a link to the site:
www.beulahprint.ie

My CSS for the dropline menu is in

Cheers,
Colm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#wwd").hover(
function() {
$(this).children("div").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).children("div").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
});

});
```

on your What We Do `<li>` give it an id of "wwd" so `<li id="wwd"><a href.....`

Comment: Thanks for the speedy replies guys. I tried all 3 scripts but I'm not doing it right, all my page content is invisible when I add the script in the <head> section. Is this jquery?

Comment: Dude, close that damn </script> tag :)

Comment: Also, i should have been more specific in my code but UL will target all UL's on your page, hence why it might also not show up. You will need to change $("ul") to $(".sub") or whatever your "What We Do" <li> is called?

Comment: Ok so now my main ul is fading.....I was hoping to get the sub menu fading (the ul that appears when you hover over "what we do"

Comment: ah ok, so stick whatever you want to hover over in the first $() and stick what you want to fade in/out where it says "this"

Comment: look dude, I'm retarded. Can you spoon feed me please? When you hover over "what we do", I want the entire submenu to fade in, and fade out when the mouse goes off the words "what we do"

Comment: k I changed <li><a class="sub" href="#"><b>what we do</b>  to  <li id="wwd"><a class="sub" href="#"><b>what we do</b>   I changed the wrong thing obviously?

Comment: sorry dude i edited it again. by looking at your source on your site you pasted in the previous edit! Try the one now...

Comment: Dude, you're a genius! Cheers man! The fade looks a little suttery, not perfectly smooth. Can this be helped? Also, this is pushing th boat out a bit, 'cos you've helped me enough already....but I'd love to have the dropline sub menu centered above "what we do"?

Comment: just give the div an id of "whateveryouwant" and in your css just put #whateveryouwant and position: relative; left: -30px; -30px may have to be adjusted, so keep changin it till its centered!

Comment: remember to accept the answer if it was right! not that i'm pushing you ;)

Comment: i noticed it doesnt fade in/out the first time you hover over it. In your css for the div put opacity: 0;

Comment: It didn't actually work, but I'm putting that down to my simplicity so I don't wanna keep hassling you :)

Comment: yeah I was wondering bout that too, which div do I put opacity: 0;?

Comment: the div that gets faded in as you hover over WWD

Comment: no worries! Accept the answer if it helped! The tick next to my answer :)

Comment: #droplinemenu {
 position: relative;
 left: -30px, -30px;
}

needs to be left: -30px;

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).stop().fadeIn("slow");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).stop().fadeOut("slow");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Since the hover-out would hide the element, how would you over it again? :)

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this....

$('#linkId').hover(function() {
    $('.subMenu').fadeIn();
});